# org-mode/babel and zsh: Getting shell sessions to work

Tags: org-mode, org-babel

I've been trying to get shell code blocks with sessions to work, but not entirely succeeding.

My setup:
emacs 26.1 (spacemacs)
org-mode 9.2.2
default shell: zsh 5.7.1

Everything seems to work fine with `sh` but it fails with `shell`.

Ordinary, non-session execution works:

```
#+begin_src shell
  echo ${TERM}
  echo ${0}
#+end_src

#+RESULTS:
| dumb         |
| /usr/bin/zsh |
```

However, when I try to add a session I don't get the result I expect

```
#+begin_src shell :session s1
  FOO=bar
  echo ${TERM}
  echo ${0}
#+end_src

#+RESULTS:
|                                                       |
| magthecomp% 

[?2004hmagthecomp% FOO=bar[?2004l |
```

and on further use of that session emacs freezes up and I have to interrupt it (`<Ctrl-g>`), for instance if I try to execute

```
#+begin_src shell :session s1
  echo ${FOO}
#+end_src
```

When I take a look at the session buffer I see the following after running those blocks

```
FOO=bar
magthecomp% echo ${TERM}
magthecomp% FOO=bar
echo ${0}
echo ${0}
echo 'org_babel_sh_eoe'
echo 'org_babel_sh_eoe'
magthecomp% echo ${TERM}echo ${0}
dumbecho /usr/bin/zsh
            echo 'org_babel_sh_eoe'
org_babel_sh_eoe
magthecomp% echo ${FOO}
echo ${FOO}echo 'org_babel_sh_eoe'
            echo ${FOO}echo 'org_babel_sh_eoe'
```

(some colour is lost when copying it)

I already toned down the theme for my shell prompt when `${TERM} == "dumb"`, but apparently that isn't enough. Any pointers on how to adjust my zsh config to make it work would be much appreciated.

Comment: Seeing this too.  Using GNU Emacs 26.2 (build 1, x86_64-apple-darwin18.5.0, Carbon Version 158 AppKit 1671.4) - via MacPorts emacs-app.  Also using zsh...

Comment: To confirm, in the session buffer your seeing the prompt is coloured (blue for me) and errors are coloured too (green for me).  Seems emacs is adding this colour and not zsh.  Could this be what org-mode babel results output is picking up, the colour codes?

Answer (score 1):

For those having this problem and using Oh My Zsh for your config, you might try changing your Oh My Zsh theme. I had this same problem and was able to fix it by changing the theme from "robbyrussell" (the default) to the "bira" theme. I suspect the problem has something to do with the special characters used in the prompt for the theme.